# Movie about a scientist that lives on a sphere with two kids

Tags: story-identification, movie

Movie about a scientist that lives on a sphere and two kids are trying to protect him from aliens that look like humans. The scientist is trying to communicate with the kids through mirrors in a truck.

Comment: If you haven't already, can I suggest you take a look at ["How to ask a good story-id question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and in which decade do you think it might've been made? Also, what do you mean by a "sphere"? A planet? A moon? Something else?

Comment: Also, can you specify the sex of the two kids? And were the kids related to one another, or just friends?